# Java Help! Current day is string with month day year message

Tags: java

TEACHERS SYNTAX.....WRONG

```
int day;
int month;
int year;

GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.printIn("Current date is  +(month+1)+“/"+day+"/"+year);
```

MY SYNTAX NO MONTH

```
int day;
int month;
int year;

GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.printLn("Current date is" + (month+1) + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

States Unclosed string literal and I have nothing to look upon to figure this out.

Comment: Go and get yourself a cup of coffee and come back.  You just have to think about what you actually want to have printed - which parts should be in quote marks (because you want the computer to print them literally) and which should be outside of quote marks (because you want the computer to work them out).

Comment: I'm not a Java girl....seriously.  This was code the professor generated and just wanted us to change what was the message....

Comment: Also - your teacher probably wrote `println`, with a lower case L, not a capital I.

Comment: Could you add the output of both codes in your question?

Comment: Main.java:21: error: unclosed string literal
 System.out.print("Current date is?  +(month+1)+ ?/? +day+ ?/? +year);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it and it was simple but everybody didn't get it completely.  It is a simple string which composes of a message and the current month/day/year!

This simple string is what messed it all up...!
    System.out.println("Current date is"+" "+(month+1)+"/"+day+"/"+year);

Yes, the System.out.print**ln** was supposed to be a little l and not Capitalized, second in order to get a space between the message and month I needed to add one with qoutes and a space in between.  Simple syntax....omg!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some quotes.

`System.out.print("Current date is " + (month+1) + "/" + day + "/" + year);`

Edit: The other answer is missing the quote before the first slash.

Comment: compilation info
Main.java:21: error: unclosed string literal
System.out.print("Current date is ?  + (month+1) + ?/? + day + ?/? + year;
                 ^
Main.java:21: error: ';' expected
System.out.print("Current date is ?  + (month+1) + ?/? + day + ?/? + year;
                                                                          ^
Main.java:24: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
3 errors